# C# and SerialPort formatting output

Tags: c#, output

I want to get position of my motor by using command "POS;", but I get this output  "a ⌂▲ yI ° y" what with this if I can get numbers?
Then from time to time I get empty answer I was answered that it take some time to get output via Serial Port. What I have to add to my code to wait until I wil get full output to show?

[Manual controller](http://driver232.rozek.sk/UIM241.pdf) (update manual)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
            sp.PortName = "COM1";
            sp.BaudRate = 9600;
            sp.Open();

            sp.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);

            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                sp.Write("ENA;");

                sp.Write("POS;");

                string msgPos = sp.ReadExisting();
                Console.WriteLine(msgPos);

                sp.Write("OFF;");
                sp.Close();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `Thread.Sleep(50)` betwen the send the write and the read command. 50 miliseconds should be enough if not try a longer time.

```
    //Do something

    sp.Write("POS;");

    Thread.Sleep(50);

    string msgPos = sp.ReadExisting();

    //Do something else
```

I can't find any command `POS;` in the manual you posted. Do you mean FBK on page 15?

Comment: Hello Michael.My fault. I update a new manual (page 28 command POS;). If you get position via FBK; it will be ok as well :)